# ¿Por qué no me funciona consulta con Ajax en ASP.NET?

Tags: ajax, asp.net, json, vb.net

Disculpen, el problema que tengo consiste en que quiero que, al darle click a un enlace se ejecute una consulta ajax y me cargue los datos encontrados en unos campos de formulario. El resultado obtenido se genera en formato JSON, la consulta se genera correctamente, pero los datos obtenidos no se cargan en los campos.

Tengo un archivo donde se cargan los registos encontrados a través de una consulta a una base de datos y me genera lo siguiente (Hasta este momento todo está bien):

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <h2>Clientes</h2>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Correo-e</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Dirección</th>
                        <th>Opción</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <span id="Contenido_lblDatos">
                        <tr>
                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Barahona</td>
                            <td>Miriam</td>
                            <td>miriam@gmail.com</td>
                            <td>71223627</td>
                            <td>San Salvador</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' href='Clients.aspx?idCli=3'>Eliminar</a>
                                <a class='btn btn-warning btn-xs btn-edit' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editar' id='3'>Editar</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </span>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Tengo un archivo llamado edit.js que es donde realizo la llamada utiliando ajax, el cuál contiene lo siguiente:

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var idCliente = this.id;

$(".btn-edit").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var idCliente = this.id;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Admin/Ajax/ObtenerCliente',
    data: { idClient: idCliente },
    success: function (data) {
        var oDato = JSON.parse(data);
        $('#enombre').val(oDato[0].Nombre);
        $('#eapellido').val(oDato[0].Apellido);
        $('#eemail').val(oDato[0].Email);
        $('#etelefono').val(oDato[0].Telefono);
        $('#edireccion').val(oDato[0].Direccion);
    }
    });
});
```

Y tengo los archivos `ObtenerCliente.aspx` y `ObtenerCliente.aspx.vb` (También la clase Cliente):

ObtenerCliente.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ObtenerCliente.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin_Ajax_ObtenerCliente" %>
```

Clase Cliente.vb:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class Cliente
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Nombre As String
    Public Property Apellido As String
    Public Property Email As String
    Public Property Telefono As String
    Public Property Direccion As String
    Public Property Login As String
    Public Property Clave As String
    Public Property Estado As Integer
End Class
```

ObtenerCliente.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Partial Class Admin_Ajax_ObtenerCliente
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim cnx As New Conexion
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        obtenerEdit(Request.Params("idClient"))
    End Sub
    Protected Sub obtenerEdit(idCliente As String)
        Dim datosCli As New DataTable
        Dim clientes As New List(Of Cliente)()
        If idCliente <> "" Then
            datosCli = cnx.consultar("SELECT * FROM tiendaasp.cliente WHERE id = " & idCliente)
            clientes.Add(New Cliente With {
                         .ID = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("id"),
                         .Nombre = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("nombre"),
                         .Apellido = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("apellido"),
                         .Email = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("email"),
                         .Telefono = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("telefono"),
                         .Direccion = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("direccion"),
                         .Login = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("login"),
                         .Clave = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("clave"),
                         .Estado = datosCli.Rows(0).Item("estado")
                         })
        End If
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(clientes)
        Response.Write(serializedResult)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Cuando se envían los datos me devuelve un código 200 (Status Code) y el response que devuelve es:

```
[{"ID":3,"Nombre":"Miriam","Apellido":"Barahona","Email":"miriam@gmail.com","Telefono":"71223627","Direccion":"San Salvador","Login":"miriam","Clave":"miriam","Estado":1}]
```

La información obtenida debería mostrarse en los inputs de un modal que se encuentran en el siguiente bloque de código:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2"><i class='fa fa-user-plus'></i> Actualizar Dtos De Cliente</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group control-group">
                <label for="enombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombres:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 controls">
                  <input runat="server" type="text" name="enombre" class="form-control" id="enombre" placeholder="Nombres" maxlength="30" required="required" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group control-group">
                <label for="eapellido" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Apellidos:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 controls">
                    <input runat="server" type="text" name="eapellido" class="form-control" id="eapellido" placeholder="Apellidos" maxlength="30" required="required" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group control-group">
                <label for="eemail" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 controls">
                    <input runat="server" type="email" name="eemail" class="form-control" id="eemail" placeholder="Correo electrónico" maxlength="100" required="required" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group control-group">
                <label for="etelefono" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Teléfono:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 controls">
                    <input runat="server" type="text" name="etelefono" class="form-control" id="etelefono" placeholder="Número de teléfono" maxlength="8" required="required" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group control-group">
                <label for="edireccion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Dirección:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 controls">
                    <textarea runat="server" name="edireccion" class="form-control" id="edireccion" placeholder="Dirección" maxlength="250" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
              <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="btn btn-md btn-success" runat="server" Text="Guardar" ></asp:Button> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Y el error, ¿Dónde está?

Comment: Disculpa, me hizo falta poner información... Al principio explico que los datos no se cargan en los campos que quiero, pero no puse información sobre esos campos... En un momento la agrego

Comment: despúes de ésta línea: var oDato = JSON.parse(data);
coloca un console.log(oDato); //¿Qué te sale?

Comment: Lo hice y me muestra los datos que necesito... Entonces, el problema es que no los muestra en los campos que necesito.

Comment: `0
:
Apellido
:
"Barahona"
Clave
:
"miriam"
Direccion
:
"San Salvador"
Email
:
"miriam@gmail.com"
Estado
:
1
ID
:
3
Login
:
"miriam"
Nombre
:
"Miriam"
Telefono
:
"71223627"`

Comment: Disculpa las molestias, ya encontré el problema... Lo que pasa, es que, por alguna razón, el ID de los campos cambia, por ejemplo: El campo con el id "enombre" es renombrado a "Contenido_enombre" y así pasa con los demás, pero igual, gracias.

Comment: ese "por alguna razón" se llama: variables definidas por ASP.net WebForms. Saludos

Comment: Jeje, sí, no sabía eso... Bueno, gracias... Igual, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que tienes corre del lado del server para los controles input, ese "runat" te va a generar ids únicos, el prefijo depende de la sección donde estés.

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="eapellido" class="form-control" id="eapellido" placeholder="Apellidos" maxlength="30" required="required" />
```

Para usar jQuery o JavaScript puro y crudo con los IDs dinámicos, realiza lo siguiente:

```
$("#<%= nombreDeTuCampo.ClientID %>")
```

Por lo tanto, el código JavaScript deberías reemplazarlo por el siguiente:

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var idCliente = this.id;

$(".btn-edit").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var idCliente = this.id;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/Admin/Ajax/ObtenerCliente',
    data: { idClient: idCliente },
    success: function (data) {
        var oDato = JSON.parse(data);
        $("#<%= enombre.ClientID %>").val(oDato[0].Nombre);
        $("#<%= eapellido.ClientID %>").val(oDato[0].Apellido);
        $("#<%= eemail.ClientID %>").val(oDato[0].Email);
        $("#<%= etelefono.ClientID %>").val(oDato[0].Telefono);
        $("#<%= edireccion.ClientID %>").val(oDato[0].Direccion);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta... Ya lo había solucionado, pero igual... Gracias.

Comment: de nada, así queda un aporte a la comunidad :)